# How do you include a caret in a custom control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on window forms application and used a caret class in my custom text box class to change caret behaviour for all custom textboxes but i am unable to find suitable reference name for my custom textbox.

```
class Caret: NativeWindow   
{  
    public Caret(Control owner)
        : base()  
    {  
        this.Parent = owner;  
        this.AssignHandle(owner.Handle);  
    }
    ~Caret()
    {
        if (!hBitmap.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
            DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        this.DestroyCaretInternal();
        this.ReleaseHandle();
    }
```

code snippet of my custom textbox class

```
public partial class ModifiedTextBox : TextBox
{

    private Caret caret;
    
    public ModifiedTextBox()
    {
        this.caret = new Caret( ) // problem here
```

Comment: Your Caret class does not have a default Constructor you are trying to call. But the error message should tell you what the problem is we can just guess what the problem is.

Comment: No overload for method 'Caret' takes '0' arguments

Comment: Have you tried passing the `ModifiedTextBox` instance to the `Caret` constructor? `this.caret = new Caret(this);`

Comment: yes collen but the caret dont changes .

Comment: In that case you should ask the author of the caret class how that one should work. I doubt it is you.